# typescript importing/exporting objects and spreading

Tags: typescript

I've been using TS for over a year and I still run into some confusion about importing and exporting. Why can't I spread an object I imported into the export object?

```
/// file1
export {
  PORT,
  SSL_CRT,
  SSL_KEY,
}
```

```
// file2
import * as env from 'file1'
// env.PORT is available at this point
export {
   ...env  // [ts] Identifier expected. [1003] 
}
```

I resolve this issue with the following but I know its not the same nor what I want.

```
// file2
import * as env from 'file1'
export default {
   ...env  // [ts] Identifier expected. [1003] 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you tried to do is re-exporting. Here is how:

```
// file2.ts
export * from './file1'
```

You can't spread the namespace module object from `import * as env`.
It is a special object and to my understanding JavaScript does not allow you to spread it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works the way you are expecting it to:

```js
// file1.ts
export {
    PORT,
    SSL_CRT,
    SSL_KEY
};
```

```js
// file2.ts
import * as env from "./file1";

console.log(env); // { PORT: 'foo', SSL_CRT: 'bar', SSL_KEY: 'baz' }

export { env };
```

```js
// file3.ts
import { env } from "./file2";

console.log(env); // { PORT: 'foo', SSL_CRT: 'bar', SSL_KEY: 'baz' }
```

So to answer your question: You don't need to use the spread operator because the object is being implicitly destructured. Why that is happening is a question for someone who is smarter than me.

Comment: As @unional correctly answered, the point isn't to expose a key 'env' but publish all the keys from file1 from file2

Comment: Ah, okay, well I'm glad you got it answered.